# Creating multiple nodes using UNWIND in NEO4J when a node already exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using UNWIND to create multiple nodes in NEO4j. The problem is if one of the node is a duplicate it will be rejected and the entire query fails. I want to be able to create multiple relationship between the same nodes if they already exist..e.g a friend could receive multiple invitations from the same person. So I have an array of objects [{email: xxx@mail.com},{email:yyy@mymail.com},...] to be invited and the email of the sponsor sponsorEmail. There is constraint on email so attempts to create a duplicate will fail and reject the entire query. The following works fine when there is no duplicate.

```
MATCH (s {email: 'sponsor@gmail.com'})
UNWIND $arrayOfObjects as invitees
CREATE (i:Invitee) MERGE (s)-[r:INVITED {since: timestamp()}]->(i)
SET i=invitees
```

I have tried substituting MERGE the CREATE thinking that the MERGE would find a MATCH and proceed to CREATE the relationship but it did not work..I still get duplicate error. Short of cleaning the arrayOfObjects before executing the query is there another way to do this? What I want is for the duplicate not to fail but to create a relationship with the existing Invitee node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to MERGE the :Invitee node along with the invitee email. As it is now, you are creating empty :Invitee nodes, and only after they are created setting the email address. You need to MERGE them *with* the email address. (also you should use a label on your first MATCH, otherwise it does an AllNodesScan...I'll assume it's :Invitee for now, but please replace with whatever label makes sense).

```
MATCH (s:Invitee {email: 'sponsor@gmail.com'})
UNWIND $arrayOfObjects as invitee
MERGE (i:Invitee {email:invitee.email}) 
CREATE (s)-[r:INVITED {since: timestamp()}]->(i)
```

Comment: @InverseFalcon...Yes I did try this as stated in the question but I got a duplicate error as stated above...I will double check. Also, thanks for the label reminder...I actually use a label however your reminder does improve the question +1

Comment: The last `MERGE` does not quite make sense, since there is a possibility that the current timestamp will match the timestamp of an existing relationship. So, the results are non-deterministic -- you may sometimes not get a new relationship. If the use case always wants a new relationship, then `CREATE` would make more sense and be more efficient.

Comment: True, I'll change this to a CREATE

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED]

Your `MERGE` could match *any* existing `Invitee`, and your SET could try to change its `email` value to a non-unique value. This is probably why you get the constraint violation.

If you want only a single `INVITED` relationship (with the latest timestamp) for each invitee, this query may do what you want:

```
MATCH (s {email: 'sponsor@gmail.com'})
UNWIND $arrayOfObjects as invitee
MERGE (i:Invitee {email: invitee.email})
ON CREATE SET i = invitee
MERGE (s)-[r:INVITED]->(i)
ON CREATE SET r.since = timestamp()
```

This query assumes that every map in `arrayOfObjects` contains a unique `email` property value. (You should also create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/schema/index/) or [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/schema/constraints/#query-constraint-unique-nodes) on `:Invitee(email)` to speed up the first `MERGE`.)

The `MERGE (s)-[r:INVITED {since: timestamp()}]->(i)` clause (which specifies the current timestamp) is flawed, since it would not detect an existing relationship with an older `since` value -- so it would almost always create a new relationship. The `MERGE (s)-[r:INVITED]->(i)` clause would only create a relationship if none exists.

Or, if you want to keep track of the timestamps of every invitation, you could make the `since` value be an array of timestamps, like this:

```
MATCH (s {email: 'sponsor@gmail.com'})
UNWIND $arrayOfObjects as invitee
MERGE (i:Invitee {email: invitee.email})
ON CREATE SET i = invitee
MERGE (s)-[r:INVITED]->(i)
ON CREATE SET r.since = [timestamp()]
ON MATCH SET r.since = r.since + timestamp()
```

Comment: I did use the MERGE after the UNWIND as stated in the question but I was still getting "Node 123 with email xxxx already exist' .  Yes I want it to create a new relationship to track how many invitations was sent to the same invitee.....I will double check my code

Comment: Your `MERGE` could match *any* existing `Invitee`, and your `SET` could try to change its `email` value to no longer be unique. Also, see my updated answer for a suggestion for how to keep track of every invitation.

Answer (score 0):

Both answer submitted are good answers. I am submitting this answer with a few nuances for those who come along later. The main objective of the question was to be able to create multiple invitations to a friend who has not yet accepted and be able to visualize those invitations. The following is what I settled on:

```
WITH ['tom@abc.com', 'tony@mymail.com',michael@gmail.com'] AS coll
UNWIND coll AS invitee
WITH DISTINCT invitee
MATCH (s:Sponsor {email: 'mary@gmail.com'})
MERGE (i:Invitee {email: invitee})
CREATE (s)-[r:INVITED {since: timestamp()}]->(i)
RETURN r;
```

This allowed me to create multiple relationships for each invite sent to the same person but only if sent at different times....which I can easily view.